# Unhandled Promise rejection with unit test and angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm currently encountering a problem when using jasmine test with promises.

The error is 'Unhandled Promise rejection:' which mean my promise don't handle `catch()` and `then()` correctly I suppose.

Here is my test :

```js
it('tests the openRepo function with changed and invalid path', (done) => {
    const OldPath = '/old';
    const NewPath = '/invalid';
    const ProjectModalBoolean = true;
    component.path = OldPath;
    component.openFolder = NewPath;
    component.projectModalLoading = ProjectModalBoolean;
    component.openRepo().then(() => {
      expect(component.openFolder).toBe('');
      expect(component.projectModalLoading).toBeFalsy();
      done();
    });
  });
```

In the function `openRepo` I have the following code :

```js
return this.gitService.setPath(this.openFolder)
          .then((data) => {
            this.projectModalLoading = false;
            this.projectModalVisible = false;
            this.openFolder = '';
            this.toastr.info(data.message, data.title);
          })
          .catch((data) => {
            this.projectModalLoading = false;
            this.openFolder = '';
            this.toastr.error(data.message, data.title);
          });
```

...which call the function :

```js
async setPath(newPath) {
        new Promise<ServiceResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (newPath === '/new') {
                resolve(new Object());
            } else {
                reject(new Object());
            }
    });
}
```

The `reject()` in the `setPath` seems to be the issue since another test going through the `resolve()` work just fine

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 2):

You have `Promise`, `resolve` and `reject` on the `setPath` method. Instead of `catch` clause use the second argument callback like follows.

```js
    return this.gitService.setPath(this.openFolder)
              .then((data) => {
                this.projectModalLoading = false;
                this.projectModalVisible = false;
                this.openFolder = '';
                this.toastr.info(data.message, data.title);
              },
              (data) => {
                this.projectModalLoading = false;
                this.openFolder = '';
                this.toastr.error(data.message, data.title);
              });
```

Read this [article](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/)

Comment: what if i dont have catch, i only have then

Comment: @jorencejovin yes. That is what I have explained here. No need to have a catch. Second argument of the `then` is the error.